# Shared element jumps before transition from activity with windowIsFloating="true"

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have an `Activity` that's using `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`. When I try to perform a shared element transition from this activity to another activity, the shared element momentarily jumps downwards by the height of the status bar before jumping back into place and properly animating into the second activity. I've narrowed down the culprit to `android:windowIsFloating`: if I set this to `false` the jump stops happening, but the activity is difficult to style properly without it. Is there some way I can correct the initial height calculation for the shared element?

Comment: As a side note, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33155646/15882) is the reason I can't use a proper dialog.

Comment: Same probleme here: android:windowIsFloating is really causing issues

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a device with a [display cutout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout)? I recently encountered something like this on a Pixel 5, and thought it was an Android issue.

Try adding `<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>` to your theme.

Comment: Display cutouts didn't exist when I asked this question.